# Tensorflow Model Garden always outputs validation loss equals zero for Instance / Semantic Segmentation

Tags: tensorflow-model-garden

I'm running the notebook of the [Instance Segmentation tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfmodels/vision/instance_segmentation) of Tensorflow Model Garden. During the training, the output of the 'Train and Evaluate' periodically displays the metrics, but the value of the validation loss is always zero.
For example:

```
eval | step:   1200 | steps/sec:    3.3 | eval time:   60.0 sec | output: 
{'AP': 0.0814979,
 'AP50': 0.16509584,
 'AP75': 0.07145937,
  ...
 'mask_ARs': 0.0015765766,
 'steps_per_second': 3.3340747415649394,
 'validation_loss': 0.0}
```

I noticed the same behavior in the Semantic Segmentation tutorial. For this tutorial, the outputs are shown on the tutorial page: https://www.tensorflow.org/tfmodels/vision/semantic_segmentation#train_and_evaluate

Is this a TensorFlow Models bug? Do I need to set any training configuration variable to calculate the validation loss?